# Dynamic SQL with C# SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-injection

I'd like to create a dynamic SQL query with c#'s `SqlCommand` where even the table is a parameter, so as to avoid injection attempts. Like below:

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE cond=@cond";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("tbl","TABLENAME");
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("cond","CONDITION");
```

However, I have found that this is not allowed. I've looked into using Dynamic SQL with an execute, but that seems to be only for stored procedures. Can I use Dynamic SQL with an Execute using parameters for the table name with an SqlCommand? If not, how can this be done to avoid SQL injection problems?

Thanks!

Comment: The names of the tables are not infinite. You could search your INFORMATION_SCHEMA and prepare a combo or a list with the allowed table names and not allow your users to type them. At this point you could risk the concatenation for the table names

Comment: @Steve Thanks Steven, but I'm not pulling from a user entered field. I'm using an object that has the tablename passed in as a parameters. It's a library of functions for some common functionality in my office. It's weird, I admit, but it works for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SqlCommandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.quoteidentifier%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to escape table names.

```
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
string tableName ="SomeTable";
string escapedTableName = builder.QuoteIdentifier(tableName);
```

Later you can use the escaped table name in your string like:

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM "+ escapedTableName +"  WHERE cond=@cond";
```

Comment: Wouldn't there still be issue with ';'? For instance say tablename was 'tablename; DELETE FROM othertable; SELECT * FROM tablename'. Would that not produce something akin to 'SELECT * FROM tablename; DELETE FROM othertable; SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE cond=1'?

Comment: @steventnorris, if your table Name has `SomeTable';` then you will end up with `[SomeTable';]`

Comment: @steventnorris, for your edited comment, No. it will be enclosed in `[]`

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with the method. So, essentially, it encases whatever is passed to it in [] regardless of content? So my edited comment would come out as 'SELECT * FROM [tablename; DELETE FROM othertable; SELECT * FROM tablename] WHERE cond=1'?

Comment: @steventnorris, yes you will get `[tablename; DELETE FROM othertable; SELECT * FROM tablename]` as the table name.

Comment: In that case, couldn't you still do tablename = 'tablename];DELETE FROM othertable; SELECT * FROM [tablename' and end up with 'SELECT * FROM [tablename]; DELETE FROM othertable; SELECT * FROM [tablename] WHERE cond=1'? Does the method handle that sort of injection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56548/discussion-between-habib-and-steventnorris).

Comment: @steventnorris, you will get `['tablename]];DELETE FROM othertable; SELECT * FROM [tablename' and end up with 'SELECT * FROM [tablename]]; DELETE FROM othertable; SELECT * FROM [tablename]] WHERE cond=1]` , the square brackets in the existing string would be escaped. You can also try the above sample lines in a sample app to get a better idea

Comment: Great. That seems to work, with the caveat of a remark letting the users of the library know they should whitelist any tablenames used with this object.

Comment: @steventnorris, if table list is available then that should always be checked.

Comment: You know.. for probably one of.. if not THEE only way to do this in code.. this answer is underwhelmingly under scored and not even easy to find when searching. Yes.. dynamic sql is bad and yes sanitising sql is the last resort.. but they dont make it easy to find the correct way to do it. ANd it leads to people making their own code which is worse than just using a standard, easy way to do it. Thanks for this answer its great!

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the table you're `select`int from is *not* user-supplied, there's nothing to worry about.

If, however, you allow dynamic specification of tables to be queried, you'll need the `QuoteIdentifier` approach suggested by @Habib and I strongly recommend whitelisting all the available table names.